# Dax to Calculate the Date difference from Due date

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image]

I wrote below Dax to calculate the date difference between due date and todays dates.
Aim is flag tasks which were missed and still not completed. i get this weird date in 1899. I have checked data types and its set to date format but still not actual date difference.

**duein = DATEDIFF(TODAY(),Task[TaskDueDate].[Date],DAY)**

Comment: What does it come through as in the PowerQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your formatting of the `duein` column. You have it formatted as a date. The numeric equivalent of 19/12/1899 is -11, which is the days difference you are looking for.

In general, MS programs store dates as the number of days difference from 31/12/1899.

Change the formatting of `duein` to number, and you should show the result you are looking for.